# Восстановление файлов с FAT под Linux

Tags: linux, fat32, recovery

На карте памяти телефона, на которой ФС fat32, странным образом из корня пропала папка с 12ГБ данными.
При этом место она на карте занимает, но в имеющихся файлах её нет.
Ещё появился странный файл с недопустимым названием, который весит всего 153МБ.

В общем охота восстановить, при этом под **linux**.

Если бы копировал на ext4, то проблем бы никаких **R-Linux** и вперёд, но бесплатный **R-Linux** с **fat**-ом не работает, а ломанной **R-Studio** под **Linux**  я не нащёл.

Есть куча бесплатных консольных утилит, например **photorec**, но они восстанавливают ни сохраняя не пути, не названия файлов, и получается просто каша какая-то.

Есть ли под **Linux** бесплатные утилиты для восстановления файлов работающие с **fat**-ом, способные просмотреть дерево файлов и выбрать что нужно восстановить, если возможно, и восстановить с оригинальными путями и именем?

Или подскажите где скачать ломанную **R-Studio** под **Linix** или тому подобную программу?

Comment: Сними дамп через `ddrescue`, а потом проскань под виндой. Если фоторек не нашёл, то не факт, что имена сохранились. И тот же r-studio 4 win наверняка покажет `000001.jpg`

Comment: Каталоги тоже могли побиться, так что ни о каких путях не может быть и речи для них. Если файлы -- просто фоточки, то это можно по экзифам разгрести, а в противном случае -- бэкапы надо иметь.

Comment: @donRumata, была бы винда под рукой, взял бы сразу ломаную R-Studio под винду.

Comment: @0andriy, В R-Linux я сразу вижу реальное дерева файлов и то что можно восстановить, что можно частично восстановить и что нельзя восстановить. Каталоги если и побились, то я тоже их вижу и мне не обязательно сканировать и восстанавливать весь диск, как с photorec.
Photorec помог, он мне выдал почти все 32 ГБ моей карты памяти, притом что я предварительно удалил всё лишнее. В самом конце его выхлопа я обнаружил все нужные мне данные. Photorec для карт памяти, ещё терпимо, но с HDD работать почти невозможно, особенно если нужно восстановить маленький текстовый файл в определённом месте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Или подскажите где скачать ломанную R-Studio под Linix или тому подобную программу?

1. recoverjpeg - восстанавливает изображения в формате jpeg
2. foremost - восстанавливает список различных форматов файлов
3. scalpel - восстанавливает список различных форматов файлов